# How can I manually trigger DOMContentLoaded?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am loading in a script (Google Tag Manager) that most likely listens for DOMContentReady events. The issue is that the script is loaded after DOMContentReady has completed. So I am looking for a way to manually trigger the DOMContentReady event (or any other native 'ready' event GTM might listen to)

I have tried with: `document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('DOMContentLoaded'))` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It is actually `document.dispatchEvent(new Event('DOMContentLoaded'))`, but I can't see why do you need to fire this event, because it might generate some errors in your scripts too?

Comment: Thanks @AdnaneAr. Turns out you were right. I had to run `dataLayer.push({ event: 'gtm.js', 'gtm.start': (new Date()).getTime(), 'gtm.uniqueEventId': 0 });` - this was specifically for GTM to work with a delayed injection.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    window.document.dispatchEvent(new Event("DOMContentLoaded", {
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true
    }));
```